# .htaccess redirect if nothing matches

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, get

I have this in my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /

RewriteRule ^login index.php?page=login [L]
RewriteRule ^settings index.php?page=settings [L]
RewriteRule ^logout index.php?page=logout [L]
```

What I am trying to achieve is if someone goes to let's say `/settings/hello/` it will redirect them back to `/`. Right now what happens is it still displays the root folder, but still has `/hello/` in the address bar.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try full URL in `ErrorDocument`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/
```

Comment: Do you have more rules than what is shown in question?

Comment: I do, but I deleted all the other rules and left these and still had the problem

Comment: I am suspecting this .htaccess is not even being used.

Comment: Thats most definitely not the case

Comment: `ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/` certainly redirects to `http://domain.com/` if a 404 is generated. Can you check `RewriteLog` and show the data in question.

Comment: My apologizes. I deleted everything again it seemed to work. I must be doing something wrong in my other parameters.